# Putting highcharts chart in OpenLayers popup?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, openstreetmap, chart

I build a openlayers map on my website.
and there are many feature vector on the map.

now I want to put a highcharts charts in popup.
to show the temperature in every city
something Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EQ2q.png)

If it is possible, then how do I do it?

I used contentHTML but it is failed

highcharts code

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Area chart with negative values'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }]
});
```

part of openlayers code

```
var content = "<div id='chart'></div>" ;
        var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
            OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
            null,       
            content,
            null,
            true
        );
```